# Return value of XXTEA

Tags: c#, c++, cryptography

This may seem a stupid question but I can't find the anwer...

This is the code for XXTEA from Wikipedia:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define DELTA 0x9e3779b9
#define MX ((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (k[(p&3)^e] ^ z));

void btea(uint32_t *v, int n, uint32_t const k[4]) {
  uint32_t y, z, sum;
  unsigned p, rounds, e;
  if (n > 1) {          /* Coding Part */
    rounds = 6 + 52/n;
    sum = 0;
    z = v[n-1];
    do {
      sum += DELTA;
      e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
      for (p=0; p<n-1; p++)
        y = v[p+1], z = v[p] += MX;
      y = v[0];
      z = v[n-1] += MX;
    } while (--rounds);
  } else if (n < -1) {  /* Decoding Part */
    n = -n;
    rounds = 6 + 52/n;
    sum = rounds*DELTA;
    y = v[0];
    do {
      e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
      for (p=n-1; p>0; p--)
        z = v[p-1], y = v[p] -= MX;
      z = v[n-1];
      y = v[0] -= MX;
    } while ((sum -= DELTA) != 0);
  }
}
```

I am porting this to C#. I don't know what I am overlooking, but where is the result of the encryption stored? I assume it is in v, but data from v is never set, only read.

What is it that I don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operators = -= += has the same priority in expressions and they are associated from right to left according to C++ Standard 5.17 (and I believe there is the same rule in C) . For example, this:

```
y = v[p] -= MX;
```

Could be replaced with:

```
v[p] -= MX; // <<< modification of data here
y = v[p];
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this page while Googling for "XXTEA C#". Couldn't find any readymade implementations, so I did my own. With the magic of closures, it's a practically verbatim copy of the reference code. I've posted it for anyone else who arrives here.

Note that while this accepts a byte array of arbitrary length, the length of the returned array will always be a multiple of four. And, unlike the reference implementation, this one returns modified data instead of changing the original.

```
using System;

namespace Encryption
{
    public enum XXTEAMode
    {
        Encrypt,
        Decrypt
    }

    static public class XXTEA
    {
        static public byte[] Code(byte[] data, uint[] k, XXTEAMode mode)
        {
            uint[] v = new uint[(int)Math.Ceiling((float)data.Length / 4)];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, v, 0, data.Length);

            unchecked
            {
                const uint DELTA = 0x9e3779b9;
                uint y = 0, z = 0, sum = 0, p = 0, rounds = 0, e = 0;
                int n = v.Length;
                Func<uint> MX = () => (((z >> 5 ^ y << 2) + (y >> 3 ^ z << 4)) ^ ((sum ^ y) + (k[(p & 3) ^ e] ^ z)));

                if (mode == XXTEAMode.Encrypt)
                {
                    rounds = (uint)(6 + 52 / n);
                    z = v[n - 1];
                    do
                    {
                        sum += DELTA;
                        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
                        for (p = 0; p < n - 1; p++)
                        {
                            y = v[p + 1];
                            z = v[p] += MX();
                        }
                        y = v[0];
                        z = v[n - 1] += MX();
                    } while (--rounds > 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    rounds = (uint)(6 + 52 / n);
                    sum = rounds * DELTA;
                    y = v[0];
                    do
                    {
                        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
                        for (p = (uint)(n - 1); p > 0; p--)
                        {
                            z = v[p - 1];
                            y = v[p] -= MX();
                        }
                        z = v[n - 1];
                        y = v[0] -= MX();
                    } while ((sum -= DELTA) != 0);
                }
            }

            byte[] rvl = new byte[v.Length * 4];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(v, 0, rvl, 0, rvl.Length);
            return rvl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One quick note, this implementation will fail with v of length 1.  Adding an early out for that case fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

In the coding part:  `z = v[n-1] += MX;`

In the decoding part:  `y = v[p] -= MX;`

Those lines are executing += on an element of the v array and then copying the new value into z or y.  Whomever wrote the code was prioritizing brevity over clarity, which is generally not a good thing in practical use.

Answer (score 1):

v is set in this line for example:

```
y = v[0] -= MX;
```

That could also be written as:

```
v[0] = v[0] - MX;
y = v[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The data in the array at the end of pointer `v` is updated, though:

```
v[p] += MX;
...
z = v[n-1] += MX;
...
z = v[p-1], y = v[p] -= MX;
...
y = v[0] -= MX;
```

So yes; it is the data *referred to* be `v` that is updated.